# Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, woocommerce-rest-api

I have this issue

> Cannot read property 'first_name' of undefined

This is my HTML File checkout.html

```html
<ion-content>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>First Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newOrder.billing.first_name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      
      ....
      
</ion-content>
```

and this is my ts file checkout.ts

```js
      this.storage.get("userLoginInfo").then((userLoginInfo) => {

      this.userInfo = userLoginInfo.user;

      let email = userLoginInfo.user.email;
      let id = userLoginInfo.user.id;

      this.WooCommerce.getAsync("customers/email/"+email).then((data) => {

        this.newOrder = JSON.parse(data.body).customer;

      })

    })
```

and this is an image of the error
[image]

Comment: Well apparently `billing` property is `undefined` like error suggests. This is asynchronous, so template is rendered before data has arrived. Of course it might be `undefined` for a reason that the prop doesn't exist, but my guess the issue is the first one.

Comment: what is inside newOrder?

Comment: i have declare it in the constuctor 
this.newOrder = {};
    this.newOrder.billing = {};
    this.newOrder.shipping = {};
    this.billing_shipping_same = false;

Comment: Okay, well then probably the data you are getting doesn't exist `billing` property. Like commented by NullPointer, what is the content of `newOrder` after assignment of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are loading the newOrder asynchronous.
As a result your page get rendered, but the async-task is not finished yet.

You wrote that you declared  `this.newOrder.billing = {}` in the constructor.
Because of that, he now tries to read `newOrder.billing.first_name` in your html.
`newOrder.billing` is an empty object, so there is no `first_name` there.

Only when the async-task has finished, this data will be existent. But currently Angular throws an error before that could happen.

There are two very common ways to handle a situation like that.

You could tell the template that it should NOT render the part with the missing data

```
<ion-item *ngIf="newOrder.billing">
  <ion-label>First Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newOrder.billing.first_name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Then the *ngIf will see that the variable is undefined and that part of the template won´t be shown in the DOM => no error :-)
As soon as the async-task  finishes, the variable is not undefined anymore and the template-part will be shown.

Another way (more common when you just want to show data) is using

    `{{ newOrder.billing.first_name | async }}`

The async-pipe will also make sure that Angular could handle that one.
In combination with [ngModel] i think the async-pipe  will not work. But it may be worth a try.

warm regards

Comment: ... well if `billing` is an empty object, how can it be `undefined` at the same time? ;)

Comment: :-) True :-) , so the alternative would be, that "JSON.parse(data.body).customer" returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just add a quotemark, i think it will help.

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newOrder?.billing.first_name"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply a quote mark with the object in your interpolation as said by
@Kraken.

But two solution provided by the @JanRecker:
if you use async pipe in your interpolation it won't work, because this works with `Observables rxjs`.

So, adding a quote mark really a helpful option.